# Mathematical background behind SVM

Tags: geometry, machine-learning

I am trying to get some intuition behind [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) algorithm by reading slides [Support Vector Machines](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/svm15.pdf) by Andrew W. Moore.

Let's consider the case of Linear SVM.

In the slides it's descrives that two planes can be defined.

plus-plane:$x:w.x+b=+1$

minus-plane:$x:w.x+b=-1$

Q: I know the plane can be defined as $n(r-r_0)=0$, however I don't understand why I can ensure that there is possible to define two planes $x:w.x+b=+1$ and $x:w.x+b=-1$, as I understood it's possible to define the separating plane as $x:w.x+b=0$ which is indeed in the middle of the plus plane and the minus plane.

In addition as I see from the formula $w.x+b=0$ is exactly $nr-nr_0=0$, where $w=n$, $b=-nr_0$, $x=r$, so obviously $b$ is a function of $w$, however we missed this information is $w.x+b=0$. It might be better to save this information, what the reason we don't use it?

On the page 7, tehre is a claim

> The vector w is perpendicular to the Plus Plane. Why?

Initially I thought it's because the construction of the formula of $w.x+b=0$ and it follows from the definition of the plane, $w=n$ and $n$ is perpendicular to the plane, so $w$ is perpendicular too.

But, there is a hint in the slides.

> Let u and v be two vectors on the Plus Plane. What is w . ( u – v ) ?

How I am supposed to use this hint?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, $w.x+b=\pm1$ are two general planes parallel to $w.x+b=0$. So, there is loss of generality in supposing them to be the canonical planes.

As for your second question, for two vectors $u$ and $v$, in the plus plane, with end points as $u_{1}, u_{2}$ and $v_{1}, v_{2}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
u=u_{1}-u_{2}\\
v=v_{1}-v_{2}\\
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, from the eqn of the canonical plane 
\begin{eqnarray}
w.u_{1,2}=w.v_{1,2}&=&1-b\\
w.(u-v)=w.(u_{1}-u_{2}-v_{1}+v_{2})&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
More generally, $w.(nu+nv)=0\ \ \forall m,n\in R$.
Thus any vector in the plus plane represented by $nu+nv$ is orthogonal to w.

So, $w$ is orthogonal to the canonical plane. (and also the separating plane)